# Scrapy reporting vague error when attempting to crawl website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, yahoo-finance

I'm building a web spider to crawl yahoo finance. I'm trying to get it to click the market index links on the home page and grab the last close value from the table on the respective market index page

```
2021-05-29 11:39:21 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2021-05-29 11:39:21 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (v3.8.5:580fbb018f, Jul 20 2020, 12:11:27) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.0, Platform macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit
2021-05-29 11:39:21 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-05-29 11:39:21 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
2021-05-29 11:39:21 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 8306af0a852a89a8
2021-05-29 11:39:21 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
```

This is the code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class YahooFinanceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Yahoo Stock Scraper"
    button_loc = '//*[@id="marketsummary-itm-0"]/h3/a[1]'
    close_loc = '//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/text()'

    def __init__(self, urls):
        self.urls=urls

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_front)

    def parse_front(self, response):
        button = response.xpath(YahooFinanceSpider.button_loc)
        button_link = button.css('a.Fz\(s\).Ell.Fw\(600\).C\(\$linkColor ::attr(href)')
        links_to_follow = button_link.extract()
        for url in links_to_follow:
            yield response.follow(url = url, callback = self.parse_pages)

    def parse_pages(self, response):
        closing_value = response.xpath(YahooFinanceSpider.close_loc).extract()
        for value in closing_value:
            print(value)
            

prices = []

urls=['https://finance.yahoo.com/']

yscraper=YahooFinanceSpider(urls)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(YahooFinanceSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: @N.Wouda it doesn't provide a stack trace, just the message that is at the top

Answer (score 0):

You should use `process.crawl(yscraper)` instead of `process.crawl(YahooFinanceSpider)`.
You are instantiating the object yscraper but not using it.